# ¿Como generar una consulta de dos llaves foraneas que apuntan a la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, join

estoy desarrollando un sistema para controlar **X** servicios, como supondran tengo una tabla llamada '**servicios**' en donde guardo todo tipo de servicios, estructuralmente la tabla es esta:

[image: Tabla servicios]

Dicha tabla contiene dos campos llamados **fidusuario_recepcion** y **fidusuario_reparacion**. El primero registra el servicio y el segundo lo atiende, asi de simple. Entonces mi problema es, como seria mi query para mandar a llamar el campo **fullname** de los dos campos antes mencionados.

Hasta ahora, he realizado la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT `servicios`.`fidusuario_recepcion`, `servicios`.`fidusuario_reparacion`, 
`usuarios`.`fullname`  
FROM `servicios`
LEFT JOIN `usuarios` on `servicios`.`fidusuario_reparacion` = `usuarios`.`idusuario`
```

Y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué le hace falta a mi consulta o como podria obtener esos dos nombres, dado ambos campos apuntan a la misma tabla?, de ante mano gracias

Comment: ¿El usuario que lo atiende (`fidusuario_reparacion`) también está registrado en la tabla `usuarios`?

Comment: Si, cuando se registra el servicio desde mi vista, se proporcionaun usuario fidusuario_recepcion y otro fidusuario_reparacion

Answer (score 1):

Lo tengo, solo había que asignar un alias para cada llave foranea, dejo codigo esperando les sirva a alguien en el futuro:

```
SELECT `s`.`fidusuario_recepcion`, `s`.`fidusuario_reparacion`, `recibe`.`fullname` 
as `urecepcion`, `repara`.`fullname` as `urepara` 
FROM `servicios` `s` 
JOIN `usuarios` `recibe` on `s`.`fidusuario_recepcion` = `recibe`.`idusuario` 
JOIN `usuarios` `repara` on `s`.`fidusuario_reparacion` = `repara`.`idusuario`
```